# Javascript keydown on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, keydown

I have some problem with this code

```
<input type="text" id="search-qq">
<script>
$('#search-qq').keypress(function(event) {alert('key pressed');});
</script>
```

This code working on my computer,
but Why this code don't work on my android(default browser,
android 2.3.6)??

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to developing a mobile website for the Android browser or core Android development?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is `alert` is for javascript, and in Android it may use `AlertDialog` not `alert`? And not any code can run in web can also run in mobile, if you want to code mobile website, you should use jQuery mobile instead, look this: [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)